Hardware Requirement for video processing of 2500 frames per second?
I have 50 cameras, each providing 1080p resolution feeds, on which I am applying video analytics and computer vision techniques using the YOLOv8n model. To meet my requirements, I need to process approximately 2,500 frames per second.
I tested this on Rtx3090 GPU with 32GB ram i was able to process 200 frames per second.
Could you suggest the appropriate hardware and GPU setup needed to achieve this? Additionally, are there cost-effective alternatives, such as using multiple Jetson AGX Orin devices or opting for a cloud-based solution?

Processing "2500 frames per second" is not the same thing as processing 50 different videos each running at 50 FPS. If the videos are handled independently then using multiple computers would be the right way to handle this. Or maybe 4 really good GPUs in one computer.

The question is what is your CPU and GPU utilization while you were getting 200fps?  Is your storage up to the task such as NVMe PCIe version 4 or 5?
